# Java returned exit code 1

Tags: java, eclipse, talend

I have this error message each time I launch Talend on my computer.

I tried several solutions :

- Adding the command -XX:-UseCompressedOops  at the end of the eclipse.ini file
- Removing and reinstalling both the JAVA JDK and JRE
- and also writing in my eclipse.ini file --> -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\server\jvm.dll

But without success.

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000030722

The error message is the following:

```
Java was started but returned exit code=1
c:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
-Xms512m
-Xmx1536m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-jar
C:\Users\bi3\Desktop\TOS_DI-Win32-r11816-v5.5.1\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher
C:\Users\bi3\Desktop\TOS_DI-Win32-r11816-v5.5.1\TOS_DI-win-x86_68.exe-nameTOS_DI-winx86_64
--launcher.library
C:\Users\bi3\Desktop\TOS_DI-Win32-r11816-v5.5.1\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810\eclipse_1309.dll
-startup
C:\Users\bi3\Desktop\TOS_DI-Win32-r11816-v5.5.1\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
-exitdata 18e8_5c
-vm C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1536m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-jar
C:\Users\bi3\Desktop\TOS_DI-Win32-r11816-v5.5.1\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
```

Comment: neither does your error-message make any sense nor does it even exist.
"java was started" and "returned exit code" is a contradiction.

Comment: It exists, it is exactly what I can see on my screen... I cannot add pictures but the message is literally : "Java was started but returned exit code=1".

Comment: yet, its a contradiction. Either a process starts up or it returns an exit code - code 0 is considered "NO_ERROR" (EXIT_SUCCESS), hence not being interpreted any further and everything else is an ACTUAL exit code. Code 1 would be INVALID_FUNCTION but im guessing java doesnt care about windows-conventions so ... yeah, one will have to look it up.

Comment: You are surely right, I do not want to argue as I am not a java specialist but it does not help saying that it is a contradiction. Do you have any idea/suggestions ?

Comment: What JDK do you have installed? And do you have a link to it in your PATH environment variable?

Comment: I have installed jdk-8u20-windows-i586 but I am not able to change the link to it in my path environment variable because Talend crashes before.

Comment: I finally managed to have access to the path to my environment variable which is the following : C:\Program Files\Java\jre7

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

Answer (score 1):

You can have this error in two condition -

1. If you have more than 1 java version installed in you system and also if you have 32 bit java version then run 32 bit executable file of talend else 64.

SOLUTION:

Remove one of the version and reset the  environmental path and then try again.

2. If you have deleted any talend file from %tmp% folder then it may error or you have deleted workspace or shifted it.

SOLUTION:

Copy your workspace to another location and then delete it from the existing location and then start talend and create new project and then import all the items from the copied workspace.